# How to specify multiple conditions using @Conditional annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am doing a Spring project for the first time and am stuck with a problem.

I have a java class:

```
@Component
@Conditional(AppA.class)
public class AppDeploy {...}
```

Now I need to modify this like:

```
@Component
@Conditional(AppA.class or AppB.class)
public class AppDeploy {...}
```

Can someone help me with how to do this? 
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple, Should have taken a little time before posting the question.
Here is how I did it.

Created a new Class:

```
public class AppAOrB implements Condition {
    public AppAOrB() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        Environment env = conditionContext.getEnvironment();
        return env.containsProperty("APP_A")||env.containsProperty("APP_B");
    }
}
```

Then used it like:

```
@Component
@Conditional(AppAOrB.class)
public class AppDeploy {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own conditional annotation which enables you to provide parameters and then you can apply the tests conditions depending on the provided parameter value:

see this post for more details: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/spring-4-conditional.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different approach.
From your code, I can conclude(Maybe I am wrong) that You have already implemented conditions `AppA.class` and `AppB.class` and You wonder how to implement the `AppAOrB.class` condition in an elegant way. When You take into account that `AppA.class` and `AppB.class` are just regular java classes, then implementation is obvious:

```
public class AppAOrB implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(@NonNull ConditionContext context, @NonNull AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return new AppA().matches(context, metadata) || new AppB().matches(context, metadata);
    }
}
```

The pros of this approach is that it follows the DRY rule.