# @Conditionalonproperty for complex objects to yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am having yaml config with the next structure:

```
  foo:
    bar:
      myComplexObject:
        firstProperty: 1000
        secondProperty: "You know the rules, and so do I"
        rickRollingExecuted: true
```

And I need to init bean only if "myComplexObject" property is present in config.

I've tried:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "foo.bar", name = "myComplexObject")
```

But in this case spring boot ignores property and do not init my bean.

But it works fine for simple structures like:

```
 foo:
    bar:
      value: 1000

@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "foo.bar", name = "value")
```

Is that possible to use @ConditionalOnProperty for complex objects ? Maybe there is some alternative to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try this:

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "foo.bar", name = {"firstProperty","secondProperty", "rickRollingExecuted"})
```

Comment: I've come across this same issue. What if `firstProperty` also has a child object?

Comment: In case of complex condition, you'd better to use @Conditional and pass your condition :https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892069/5230585