# How to make Spring @ConditionalOnProperty check by if an property is present without value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Well, my own project has a special config file, it can set multi-source of Redis

```yaml
my:
  redis:
    connections:
      - name: redis-1
        address: 127.0.0.1:6379
        mode: master
      - name: redis-2
        address: 127.0.0.1:6479
        mode: slave
        ofSlave: redis-1
      - name: redis-3
        address: 127.0.0.1:6579
        mode: slave
        ofSlave: redis-1
```

I try to build an Auto-Configuration Class and it will be loaded on property detected

```
// @Configuration // controll by @EnableMyRedis
@ConditionalOnProperty("my.redis.connections")
public class MyRedisAutoConfiguration {

}
```

So I want to load this Configuration and other Components when my `application.yml` file contains the property `my.redis.connections`, even though is does not have value.

---

Addition:

Things I really want can be expressed as this example, an `AutoConfiguration` and a `PropertyBeanDefinitionRegistrar`

```
@Import(AutoConfiguration.class)
public @annotation EnableMyRedis {
}

@MyConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.redis.connections")
@Import(PropertyBeanDefinitionRegistrar.class)
public class AutoConfiguration {

}

public class PropertyBeanDefinitionRegistrar implements
    EnvironmentAware, BeanDefinitionRegistrar {

}
```

It's very clear to see their relationship;

1. If Have Enabled, then load `AutoConfiguration`, otherwise not
2. If Have property-prefix 'my.redis.connections', then load `PropertyBeanDefinitionRegistrar`, otherwise not
3. In this step, property-file will be really dealed and generating beans.

---

But I enabled `debug: true` and found it doesn't work, the `PropertyResolver` or Environment in method `getMatchOutcome` of Class `OnPropertyCondition` only checked the real property instead of layer relation

How can I achieve my needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Conditionalonproperty for complex objects to yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228084/conditionalonproperty-for-complex-objects-to-yaml)

Comment: @1615903 thanks but not yet, I wanna to specify one or more upper layer prefix which not considered lower layer what really need. To be exact, what I really want is spreate the `Prefix` and `Config`, in my Configuration class, I just assure the prefix is immutable and others will be dealed by Properties and Parser, though some property will change it's name or even new or deleted, but configuration don't care, that's my expects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@ConditionalOnProperty` enables bean registration only if an environment property is present and has a specific value.

This means that you cannot use it to check if the property is present in the `application.yml` or `application.properties` file.

I think you have 2 options

---

**Option 1: Add a new property in the application properties**

You can add a new property in the application properties file.

For example:

```yaml
my:
  redis:
    enabled: true
    connections:
      - name: redis-1
        address: 127.0.0.1:6379
        mode: master
      - name: redis-2
        address: 127.0.0.1:6479
        mode: slave
        ofSlave: redis-1
      - name: redis-3
        address: 127.0.0.1:6579
        mode: slave
        ofSlave: redis-1
```

The new property `my.redis.enabled` is not required to be mapped by the object used to map the connection properties, so it should not affect how you read the configuration.

Now you can use `my.redis.enabled`

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty("my.redis.enabled")
public class MyRedisAutoConfiguration {}
```

This is the simplest and better solution IMO

---

**Option 2: Implement Custom Condition**

You can map the configuration in a class, for example:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.redis")
public class RedisConnectionProperties {
    
    private Map<String, String> connections;

    public Map<String, String> getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    public void setConnections(Map<String, String> connections) {
        this.connections = connections;
    }

}
```

And then implement a custom condition that will check if the `Map` of Redis connection that was mapped to `RedisConnectionProperties` is empty:

```java
public class RedisConnection implements Condition {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    RedisConnectionProperties config = Binder.get(context.getEnvironment())
        .bind("my.redis",RedisConnectionProperties.class)
        .orElse(null);
    return config != null && config.getConnections() != null && !config.getConnections().isEmpty();
  }
}
```

Finally, you can use this condition on `MyRedisAutoConfiguration`:

```java
@Conditional(RedisConnection.class)
public class MyRedisAutoConfiguration {}
```